# The connection to the base is not closed

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, mysql2

I am using mysql2 to work with a database.
When the trigger to remove the reaction from the message is processed, the connection is not closed, it passes the `.end ()` command, but does nothing

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const mysql_cfg = require('../mysql_cfg.json');

module.exports.run = async (messageReaction, user) => {

  try {

    var con = mysql.createPool(mysql_cfg).promise();

  if (user.bot != true) {

    if (messageReaction._emoji.id === '812934232799969361' && messageReaction.message.author.id === '789484089736429589' && messageReaction.message.embeds[0].author.name === 'Destiny 2') {   
      
      if (messageReaction.message.embeds[0].fields[0].value.search(user.id) >= 0) { 
        
      } else {

      let a = messageReaction.users.cache.filter(val => val.bot === false)
      let b = a.map(v => v.id)
      let sbor_notification = ""

      await con.execute(`UPDATE events SET users = '${b}', json_users = '${sbor_notification}' WHERE id = '${messageReaction.message.id}'`);

    messageReaction.message.edit("@here"); 
    } 
    }
  }
con.end();
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
}
};
```

Comment: Hi! welcome to stackoverflow! I recommend you to have a look at this post about how to ask great questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also, let me recommend you to build your sql queries using prepared statements or similar approaches, because the way you build it is prone to sql injection attacks: https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection

Comment: finally, to close the db connection no matter what, have you checked the `finally` statement for the `try...catch`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch#the_finally-block